# Name for a singular noun that is used like a plural?

Tags: nouns

Is there a word for a noun that is singular but can be used like it is plural?

For example...

> Q: How is your team doing?
>
> A: They are doing great.

Or

> Manchester United are at the top of the league table.

Another

> Liverpool have won a lot of games this season.

"Team" and "Manchester United" are both singular but they are regularly referred to like a plural.

*I have no idea why I fixated so much on Football based examples... I don't even like football.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about collective nouns. Here's a handy guide I pulled from the [Canadian Government's Translation Bureau](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=95TrTtTB_flE.html):

**Singular and plural verbs with collective nouns**
-A plural collective noun takes a plural verb: Families enjoy this restaurant.

-A singular collective noun usually takes a singular verb: Our family enjoys this restaurant.

-But there are some cases where a singular collective noun actually expresses a plural idea and needs a plural verb. The guidelines below will help you decide whether a singular collective noun takes a singular or plural verb.

**When to use a singular verb**
-When all the members of a collective noun are performing an action as a unit (and that’s usually the case), use a singular verb.

-The chamber orchestra often plays at the Art Centre.
The cast is celebrating the success of the play with a party after the performance.

-A wolf pack hunts as a group.

-The fleet was anchored in the channel.

**When to use a plural verb**
When the members of a collective noun are performing an action as individuals, use a plural verb. In this case, all or some members of the group are doing something independently of the other members; the group is not acting together as a unit.

-The orchestra are tuning their instruments.

-The cast have been practising their lines.

-The flock were running off in every direction.

-The staff disagree on the proposal.

**In many cases, it may sound more natural to make the subject plural in form by adding a word like members:**

-The members of the orchestra are tuning their instruments.

-The cast members have been practising their lines.

-The staff members disagree on the proposal.